# Retrieving an image over HTTP in Python

Tags: python, sockets, http

Am reading from a free ebook called "Python for Informatics".

I have the following code:

```
import socket
import time

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg HTTP/1.0\n\n')

count = 0
picture = ""

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(5120)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    # time.sleep(0.25)
    count = count + len(data)
    print len(data), count  
    picture = picture + data

mysock.close()

# Look for the end of the header (2 CRLF)
pos = picture.find("\r\n\r\n")
print 'Header length',pos
print picture[:pos]

# Skip past the header and save the picture data
picture = picture[pos+4:]
fhand = open("stuff.jpg","w")
fhand.write(picture)
fhand.close()
```

I have no knowledge in http and am having a hard time understanding the above code!

I think I do understand what mysock.connect() and mysock.send() do however I need explanation of the 1st line: **1)** `mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` . What does it do?

Now, about the line: **2)** `data = mysock.recv(5120)`. It created a var called data in which saves 5120 bytes its time the while loop run. But what type of data is this data and what happens when I run: `picture = picture + data` ? It's picture = "" + data,

- so it adds a string to what? If am right, data has both string data
  (header) + jpeg file

???

and finally: **3)**

```
pos = picture.find("\r\n\r\n")
print 'Header length',pos
print picture[:pos]
```

`pos = picture.find("/r/n/r/n")`, this searches inside picture variable to find 2 new lines "/n/n" because we used the line `mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg HTTP/1.0\n\n')`??
Is there any way to instantly save the jpeg file on our hard drive without retrieving the http header and seperating the header from the jpeg file?

Sorry for my English... Feel free to ask something that you may don't understand!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The line `mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` calls the `socket` class from the `socket` library to create a new network endpoint. `socket.AF_INET` tells the call to create an IP-based socket, and `socket.SOCK_STREAM` requests a stream-oriented (TCP) socket, which automatically sends any necessary acknowledgements and retries as appropriate.
2. The statement `data = mysock.recv(5120)` reads chunks of *up to* 5120 bytes. When there is no more data the `recv()` call returns the empty string. The test seems rather perverse, and it would IMHO be better to use `if len(data) == 0` or even `if not len(data)`, but this is a detail of style rather than substance. The statement `picture = picture + data` therefore accumulates the response data 5120 bytes at a time (though the naming is poor, because the accumulated data actually includes the HTTP headers as well as the picture data).
3. The statement `pos = picture.find("\r\n\r\n")` seeks inside the returned string to locate the end of the HTTP headers. Since it finds the beginning rather than the end of the string, 4 must be added to the offset to give the starting position of the picture data.

The example given is attempting to demonstrate low-level access to HTTP data without, apparently, giving you sufficient background about what is going on. A more normal way to access the data would use a higher-level library such as `urllib`. Here's some code that retrieves the image much more simply:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> response = urllib.urlopen("http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg")
>>> content = response.read()
>>> outf = open("cover.jpg", 'wb')
>>> outf.write(content)
>>> outf.close()
```

I could open the resulting JPEG file without any issues.

**EDIT 2020-10-09** A more up-to-date way of obtaining the same result would use the `requests` module to the same effect, and a context manager to ensure correct resource management.

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get("http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg")
>>> with open("result.jpg", "wb") as outf:
...     outf.write(response.content)
...
70057
>>>
```

Comment: Could you explain me what kind of data does The statement picture = picture + data handle? the variable data contains both string and a picture? Its like data = (http header) + a picture file? OR is it data = (header) + "http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg" which means 2 strings?

Comment: The response is a single stream made up of HTTP headers (terminated by a double CRLF, which represents a blank line) followed by the response data. The whole stream has to be retrieved, which happens in chunks of 5120 bytes, and then the HTTP headers must be ignored since you are only interested in the image data. You can think of the response as two concatenated strings, but of course in reality it's just a single data stream.

Comment: For more information you might want to read this simple article on [the structure of HTTP requests and responses](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#structure)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

1. Your first question has been asked and answered several times on SO.  The short answer is, "It's just a technicality; you don't really need to know."
2. You are correct.
3. The header ends with two CRLF.  If you save the file without discarding the header, it won't be in JPEG format, and you won't be able to use it.  The header is there to permit the file to be transmitted over the internet.  You have to discard it and save only the payload.

Comment: 1. ok, got it!

2. is that acceptable? I need to undestand that more... is that something like picture = (string) + picture(a true picture file), OR picture = (string) + blablabla.jpeg (which is also a string)?

3. got it too!